# How to add remote vm instance as worker node in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I'm new to kubernetes and trying to explore the new things in it. So, my question is

Suppose I have existing kubernetes cluster with 1 master node and 1 worker node.  Consider this setup is on AWS, now I have 1 more VM instance available on Oracle Cloud Platform and I want to configure that VM as worker node and attach that worker node to existing cluster.

So, is it possible to do so? Can anybody have any suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

I would instead divide your clusters up based on region (unless you have a good VPN between your oracle and AWS infrastructure)

You can then run applications across clusters. If you absolutely must have one cluster that is geographically separated, I would create a master (etcd host) in each region that you have a worker node in.

Comment: That's really great suggestion.  Can you please suggest any article or place where I can get some more information regarding how to configure etcd host for this.

Answer (score 0):

Worker Node and Master Nodes communication is very critical for Kubernetes cluster. Adding nodes from on-prem to a cloud provider or from different cloud provider will make lots of issues from network perspective.

As VPN connection between AWS and Oracle Cloud needed and every time worker node has to cross ocean (probably) to reach master node.

**EDIT**: From Kubernetes Doc, Clusters cannot span clouds or regions (this functionality will require full federation support).
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/multiple-zones/